# R using map to illustrate the frequency of values in a df of location data

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to figure if I can use R to do a map plot like the picture below.

using a DF that shows the unique location and its frequency

e.g.

[image]

[image]

I got my df (map_plot) by entering the below code

> map_plot <- st_as_sf(start_station_lat_long_count, coords = c('start_lng', 'start_lat' ))

tried to set crs with the following

> map_plot <- st_set_crs(map_plot, crs = 4326)

but it returned a error

*Error in st_set_crs(map_plot, crs = 4326) : unused argument (crs = 4326)*

Which I then tried to run a plot

> ggplot(map_plot) +
> geom_sf(aes(color = cluster))

but it returned a error

*Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cluster' not found*

Comment: Could you please share any code and your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: hi hi i have edited my questions, u can see the code i used at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

As for the first issue, use:

```
st_crs(map_plot) <- 4326
st_crs(map_plot)
```

As for the second, I don't see any mention of a variable named `cluster` anywhere? Do you mean `n` (by the look of your screenshot)?